# Why does this code of merge and merge sort algorithm does not work?

Tags: c, mergesort

1.Can you help me in looking for the error in the code?
'This is the merge function.'

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    void merge(int arr[],int left,int mid,int right)
    {
        int i,j,k;/*FOR USING IN THE FOR LOOP*/
        int n1,n2;/*For the number of elements*/
        n1=mid-left+1;
        n2=right-mid;
        int a1[n1],a2[n2];
        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
            a1[i]=arr[left+i];
        }
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            a2[i]=arr[mid+1+j];
        }
        i=0;
        j=0;
        k=left;
        while(i<n1 && j<n2)
        {
            if(a1[i]<=a2[j])
            {
                arr[k]=a1[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[k]=a2[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while(i<n1)
        {
            arr[k]=a1[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<n2)
        {
            arr[k]=a2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    
    }
```

'This is the mergesort function'

```
void mergesort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
    if(left<right)
    {
    int mid=left+(right-left)/2;
    mergesort(arr,left,mid);
    mergesort(arr,mid+1,right);
    merge(arr,left,mid,right);
}}
```

'The Main Function'

```
void main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Enter the number of elements in the array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the Element %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    mergesort(arr,0,n-1);
    printf("The Elements in the array sorted are:");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d->",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I could not find error in this code but the compiler could not compile the code and give a valid solution of the algorithm.

So pls help me to find the solution in this code.

Comment: What data did you enter?  What result did you get?  Where is the function you use to print sections of an array so that you can see what's going on?  How have you been debugging the code?

Comment: Print the arrays `a1` and `a2` in `merge()` after the loops initializing them.  I think you will find `a2` is incorrect; maybe `a1` is too.